# Cocos2d-js class extension

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I'm trying to extend the cc.LabelTTF class in cocos2d-js.
I'm having problems with the following code:

```
var FlowingText = cc.LabelTTF.extend({
    update : function(dt) {
        console.log("update. dt:"+dt);
    }
});
```

I'm expecting FlowingText to have succeeded all the properties of cc.LabelTTF, but the following code crashes:

`FlowingText.create("", "r-mplus-1c-m.ttf", 24);`

giving me the error that

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

The code works fine if I instead do:

`cc.LabelTTF.create("", "r-mplus-1c-m.ttf", 24);`

the 'create' function is a property of cc.LabelTTF, which I think I've extended, yet I'm getting this error. Any ideas what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue.

When you use `extend` to create your own class from a `cc` class, the `create` method is not inherited. If you take a peek at any of cocos2d's classes you'll notice that the `create` method is always being appended to the prototype and for some reason this bypasses the extend mechanism.

In short: you have to override the `ctor` method and or write your own `create` method.

This is the standard way it's made in coco's code files:

```
var FlowingText = cc.LabelTTF.extend({
    ctor: function(text, font, size){
        this._super(text, font, size);
        //possibly do other stuff here if necesary
    },
    update : function(dt) {
        console.log("update. dt:"+dt);
    }
});
```

And you can use this with:

```
var myFT = new FlowingText("asdf", "r-mplus-1c-m.ttf", 24);
```

And/or you could do this:

```
FlowingText.create = function(text, font, size) {
    return new FlowingText(text, font, size);
};
```

And use it like this:

```
var myFT = FlowingText.create("asdf", "r-mplus-1c-m.ttf", 24);
```

Extra: note that `cc.LabelTTF.create()` and `new cc.LabelTTF()` may not necessarily be the same. When you override the `ctor` method you are changing what it's called with `new MyClass()`. If you try to override the `create` method within your `extend`you'll get an error (or at least this was the case last time I tried).

Comment: I'm glad it did!
And thanks @musikov! Those were some dumb errors on my part '^^

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
var FlowingText = $.extend(cc.LabelTTF, {
 update : function(dt) {
        console.log("update. dt:"+dt);
    }})
```

it should work now `FlowingText.create("", "r-mplus-1c-m.ttf", 24);`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6fvdJ/2/)

Comment: I took a look at your demo and it does not quite do what you think (plus you have some small syntax errors -or rather, warnings-). Additionally, you are not reflecting how the code structure of the cocos2d-html5 clases work, take a look at my answer for clarification.